# Arduino: Change position of where the next byte is read on a file

Tags: text, position, sd-card, arduino-uno

I'm using an XDRduino UNO with an Ethernet Shield. On it I have a micro sd card with a text file. I want to read a specific line of text from the file based on line number. The file is very large so I can't store everything in an array, and I can't store each line in an array and then clear the array because, for example, that code takes a minute to run for line number 65000.

I formatted the file with Python so that all the lines are the same length. My idea was to use the seek() function to change the position that the file is read from (multiplying line length by line number to view the line that I want). The problem is that neither the seek() nor seekSet() functions are changing the position from where the next byte is read. I also tried changing the value of the position() function, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

```
 #include <SD.h>
File myFile;
char StringList [50];   
int ListIndex = 0;
char character;




void setup()                    // run once, when the sketch starts
{
  Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
   //just added
   while (!Serial) {
  }
   //end of just added

  Serial.println("Hello world!");  // prints hello with ending line break 
  //just added
  Serial.print("Initializing...");
 pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

 if(!SD.begin(4)){
 Serial.println("Failure");
 return;
 }

 Serial.println("Initialization done.");
  //end of just added
  //myFile = SD.open("AverageVoltageOutputspassiveFilterHigherRes.txt");
  myFile = SD.open("testing.txt");
 if (myFile) {                  
    while (myFile.available()){
      //myFile.seek(500); //THIS DOES NOT CHANGE POSITION
      if (myFile.position() == 500) {
      character = myFile.read(); 
        if (character != 0X0A) { 
          StringList[ListIndex] = character;
          ListIndex++;       
        }else {
            ListIndex++; 
             Serial.println(StringList);
              break;  
       }
      }
      else{
        Serial.println("File Position Wrong");
        break;
      }
  }
 }  

else {  
  Serial.println("Log!");
}
}


void loop()                       // run over and over again
{
                                  // do nothing!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you don't need semicolons in Python unless you're putting multiple statements on a line, but that's not why you're here :-)

Python defaults to opening lines in *text mode*.  Unfortunately, you cannot seek when you do that.

It is perfectly fine to open files in *binary mode* even if they are text files.  I do that all the time.  It just means that you have to be cognizant of whether the line ending is \n, \r, or \r\n.  So, anyway, to do that:

```
myFile = SD.open("testing.txt", 'rb')
```

And then myFile.seek() will magically work.